# Dynamically update options in selectfield depending on another Select Field's data of another Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible? If yes, then how? Please, give an example, because I can't find it anywhere. (I found the example of dynamically update options depending on another select field's data but in the same form).

Comment: You would need to add an EventListener to the select on which depending you want to change the other selectfields options. In the callback function of the EventListener you must filter the available options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an eventlistener to the change of the select and based on value change any other element.

```js
const select1 = document.querySelector('.select_1');
const option1 = document.querySelector('.select_2 option:first-of-type');
select1.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(this.value === 'b'){
    option1.textContent = 'newA';
    option1.setAttribute('value','newA');
  } else {
    option1.textContent = 'A';
    option1.setAttribute('value','a');    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="select_1">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form>
  <select class="select_2">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this using JQuery:

```js
 // Hide all options initially
    $('#selectChild option').attr('disabled',true);
    // When the user changes the Parent select (Animal Category)
    $(document).on('change', '#selectParent', function() {

      // Assign the value of the selected option to variable
      let category = $('#selectParent option:selected').val();

      // Run through each Child select (Animal Name) option and filter based on its data-* attribute value

      $('#selectChild option').filter(function() {
        if ($(this).data('category') != category) {
          $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        } else {
          $(this).attr('disabled',false);
        }
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>
  Animal Category
</h5>
<select id="selectParent">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="mammal">Mammal</option>
  <option value="insect">Insect</option>

</select>
<br>
<hr>
<h5>
  Animal Name
</h5>
<select id="selectChild">
  <option> Please Select </option>
  <option value="dog" data-category="mammal">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat" data-category="mammal">Cat</option>
  <option value="horse" data-category="mammal">Horse</option>

  <option value="spider" data-category="insect">Spider</option>
  <option value="ant" data-category="insect">Ant</option>
  <option value="roach" data-category="insect">Roach</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` cross browser. Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Comment: @charlietfl that is correct. I used these shorthand methods of this for the example. Another option for this according to [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3Ablock), is to use the `css()` method and change the value between the `display` property. Setting `css('display','none')` in place of the `hide()` method etc... Which is supported by all browsers.

Comment: No ...`display:none` is not supported on `<option>` element cross browser. You are missing the point. Also `hide()` in jquery does same thing as `css('display','none')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @charlietfl Ah okay I'm on the same page now - I'll update my answer